# Performing an operation on some elements of a vector

Tags: r, vectorization

I know how to 'extract' some elements from a vector meeting some given condition, in R —for instance:

```
x = c(10, 20, 30, 40)
x[x<25]
```

Result:

```
[1] 10 20
```

What I would like is to apply an operation to some given elements of a vector, without either modifying or loosing the rest of elements. For instance:

```
x = c(10, 20, 30, 40)
y = numeric(length(x))  # create a vector with as many zeros as elements in `x`
```

And now, I want to make `y[i]` equal to 10 times `x[i]`, only if `x[i]>25`, using vectorisation, of course.

Comment: What is the expected `y`, is it not `c(10, 20, 300, 400)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a job for **ifelse**:

```
# Your data
x = c(10, 20, 30, 40)

# Multiplying with ten if condition is met else zero
ifelse(x>25, x*10, 0)
[1]  0  0 300 400
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
(x > 25) * (10 * x)
#[1]   0   0 300 400
```

To break it down

```
(x > 25) #gives
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

(10 * x)
#[1] 100 200 300 400
```

Now when you multiply it together `FALSE` is evaluated to 0 whereas `TRUE` to 1. So numbers greater than 25 are multiplied by 10 whereas less than equal to 25 are multiplied to 0.

---

As an alternative to `ifelse` we can also use `replace`

```
replace(x * 10, x <= 25, 0)      
#[1]   0   0 300 400
```

---

Bencharmking on length `1e6` data

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- sample(1:50, 1e6, replace = TRUE)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(mul = (x > 25) * (10 * x), 
               ifelse = ifelse(x>25, x*10, 0), 
               replace = replace(x * 10, x <= 25, 0))


Unit: milliseconds
#   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
#    mul  6.654335  12.74489  15.93877  14.22821  15.03979  70.48483   100 a  
# ifelse 89.945089 112.12242 126.15313 120.03759 135.84350 432.44697   100 c
#replace 11.711879  18.30549  27.78782  20.75061  21.96056 395.21573   100 b
```

---

---

In case, if we want to keep `x` as it is and change only for `x > 25` we can do

```
c(1, 10)[(x > 25) + 1] * x
#[1]  10  20 300 400
```

Comment: Not only is this hacky and less legible than the `ifelse` solution, it also only works if the wanted value for the negative case is 0. @Ronak Is there any advantage compared to `ifelse`?

Comment: @antoine-sac yes, just updated the "advantage" in the answer.

Comment: @antoine-sac I agree that `ifelse` is easy to understand as it is simple "if condition is true do this or else do this" but if you could understand the logic this is simple too. For cases like this I would prefer using this solution than using `ifelse`. I am not sure what you mean by `works if the wanted value for the negative case is 0`

Comment: Impressive speed-up! Didn't expect such a big difference. Definitely worth the hack on massive datasets. Re the wanted value of 0, indeed you can complexify the formula to get around it so ignore me.

Answer (score 1):

I figured how to do this. I suppose it is very easy for those who work with R on a daily basis; I post it here, just in case it helps someone:

```
x = c(10, 20, 30, 40)
y = numeric(length(x))  # create a vector with as many zeros as elements in `x`
ii = (x>25)  # vector of boolean values
y[ii] = 10*x[ii]  # performs the operation only on/for those elements for which `ii` is true
y
```

Result:

```
[1]   0   0 300 400
```

Hope you find it useful.

Comment: You are overcomplicating. A simple `ifelse` statement would suffice here, i.e. `ifelse(x > 25, 10*x, 0)`

Comment: @RonakShah I wanted them to be zero, actually.

Comment: @Sotos I didn't know about `ifelse`. I see it is simpler. Is it also faster, computationally speaking?

Comment: It should be faster too yes but I can't say for sure. You can check the `benchmark`